# Media queries are replacing another media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a few media queries, but one replace my class properties of the other. For example, when i am on 1024 px width it show this:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -7em !important;
  left: 44%;
}
```

And i have another class for 1366px:

```
@media (min-width: 1366px)
.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -8em !important;
  left: 44%;
}
```

But when i am on 1366, the class of 1024 is still active, replacing the 1366 class styles (So, it add top: -7em instead top: -8em). How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post your example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: You should probably stop using `!important`, that is just asking for trouble of this sort.

Comment: @Peter Are you tested it in all browsers or any specific browser?

Comment: Did you consider the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)? (the second rule declared after the first one)

Comment: both conditions are true if width screen is > 1366, so it will replace the values of the same classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (min-width:1024px) and (max-width: 1365px)
  .box:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -8em !important;
    left: 44%;
  }  

@media (min-width: 1366px)
.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -8em !important;
  left: 44%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the first rule to only apply between 1024 and 1366 pix, you can also set a max-width:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1365px) {
  .box:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -7em !important;
    left: 44%;
  }
}
```

However, the second media query uses the exact same selector and properties (with different values) so that should overwrite the first media query.

In which order do these appear in your code? If the 1024px rule comes later in your code than the 1366px rule, it will override the rules for 1366px. In that case, switch them around.